# Vertical UISliders and UISwitches

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to set up UISwitches and UISliders vertically rather than horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not a good idea to modify the standard iOS controls like UISlider or UISwitch, it's very easy to write your own custom UIControl.  See Mike Ash's ["Diagonal Slider"](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-23-implementing-a-custom-slider.html) post

Answer (score 11):

As like Caleb said, it may violate the guideline.But am not sure about that.

If you really want to change the here is a sample ,

```
urSlider.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(urSlider.transform,270.0/180*M_PI);
```

The above code will change the slider position from horizontal to vertical.Same like this you can do for UISwitch.

Comment: need to make sure that "Use Autolayout" checkbox is unchecked under "File Inspector"

Answer (score 8):

I am looking to do the same. From the [Apple Developer Site iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html):

Slider

Appearance and Behavior

A slider consists of a track and a thumb (a circular control that the user can slide) and optional images that convey the meaning of the right and left values. When people drag the thumb along the slider, the value or process is updated continuously and is displayed in the track.

Guidelines

Use a slider to give users fine-grained control over values they can choose or the operation of the current process.

If appropriate, customize the appearance of a slider. For example, you can do any of the following:

Display a slider either horizontally or vertically.

Set the width of a slider to fit in with the UI of your app.

Define the appearance of the thumb, so that users can see at a glance whether the slider is active.

Supply images to appear at both ends of the slider to help users understand what the slider does.Typically, these custom images correspond to the minimum and maximum values of the value range that the slider controls. A slider that controls font size, for example, could display a very small character at the minimum end and a very large character at the maximum end.

Define a different appearance for the track, depending on which side of the thumb it is on and which state the control is in.

---

There do not seem to be prohibitions against changing switches, steppers, and segmented controls. However, permission does not appear to be explicitly granted for those controls.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to use UISlider vertically with a CGAffineTransformation (Set to 90 degrees).. But it doesn't work. It works until 45 degrees. So my guess is UISlider is not made to detect vertical finger slide movement.

Comment: You're aware that CGAffineTransforms work using radian units instead of degrees? Instead of a 90 degree transform, go for π/2 with your unit? Just in case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversions

Answer (score 0):

**To make a slider Vertically try this**

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 270, 160, 30)];
CGAffineTransform sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(sliderRotation,-(M_PI / 2));
slider.transform = sliderRotation;
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

Answer (score -1):

Those controls don't have a built-in vertical orientation option. It's possible that you could rotate them simply by applying an appropriate transform, but it's probably not a good plan if you hope to distribute your app through the app store. See section 10.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines, which tells you that you risk rejection for misusing standard controls.

Comment: It is fairly common to rotate certain controls like the UISlider and UISwitch, especially the slider. Wish Apple had a built-in one to make this easier for auto layout.