# Custom Storyboard Objects

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to create a storyboard object that looks like a lever and returns a number value like the UISlider. The lever will go from top to bottom on the screen. I dont know if I need to create a custom object (if so, I dont know how to) or if there is a better way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The [UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) images can be changed, and you can rotate the view to be vertical.  However, depending on exactly what you want to accomplish you might still want the extra flexibility of creating your own custom view.  Personally, I would go the custom route.

There are numerous tutorials on the web for how to accomplish this.  You'll have a much better chance of getting a good answer here once you've given it a shot on your own.  Then you can come back with more specific questions about your code.

Related: [Vertical UISliders and UISwitches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240710/vertical-uisliders-and-uiswitches)

Comment: how do i rotate and change the image of the slider?

Comment: `mySlider.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(mySlider.transform, 270.0 / 180 * M_PI);`